# Is there a way to use the data from Google Cloud Storage directly in Colab?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory

I want to use a dataset (170+GB) in Google Colab. I have two questions:

1. Since the available space in Colab is about 66GB, is there a way to use the data from GCS directly in colab, if the data is hosted in GCS? If not, what is a possible solution?
2. How can I upload the dataset to GCS directly from a downloadable link, since I cannot wget into colab due to the limited available space?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Authenticate :

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

install google sdk:

```
!curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

init the SDK to configure the project settings.

```
!gcloud init
```

1 . Download file from Cloud Storage to Google Colab

```
!gsutil cp gs://google storage bucket/your file.csv .
```

2 . Upload file from Google Colab to Cloud

```
gsutil cp yourfile.csv gs://gs bucket/
```

Hope it helps. [Source](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-access-files-from-google-cloud-storage-in-colab-notebooks-8edaf9e6c020)

Comment: I would recommend to use google ai notebooks if possible, it saves us from these kind of nagging issues.

Comment: "Source" link no longer working.

Comment: You can refer to https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/gcs.ipynb for more details

Answer (score 0):

I have a working example, that uses `tf.io.gfile.copy` ([doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/copy)).

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Getting file names based on patterns
gcs_pattern = 'gs://flowers-public/tfrecords-jpeg-331x331/*.tfrec'
filenames = tf.io.gfile.glob(gcs_pattern)

#['gs://flowers-public/tfrecords-jpeg-331x331/flowers00-230.tfrec',
# 'gs://flowers-public/tfrecords-jpeg-331x331/flowers01-230.tfrec',
# 'gs://flowers-public/tfrecords-jpeg-331x331/flowers02-230.tfrec',
#...

# Downloading the first file
origin = filenames[0]
dest = origin.split("/")[-1]
tf.io.gfile.copy(origin, dest)
```

After that if I run the `ls` command, I can see the file (`flowers00-230.tfrec`).

In some cases you may need authentication (from G.MAHESH's answer):

```py
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```